# can the layout editor be extracted from eclipse and run stand alone?

Tags: android, android-layout

Any way to use the android layout editor as a stand alone tool just to edit a single xml file outside of eclipse?

Comment: just to  clarify, you  do mean the  drag and drop editor in eclipse correct?

Comment: I don't know. I just read all this stuff about the new and improved GUI builder in the eclipse plugin, but I'd rather rub ground glass in my eyes than use eclipse, so I just thought I'd ask if the tool could run stand alone. I have no idea if it uses drag and drop or not.

Comment: AFAIK it is drag and drop (ish) and also AFAIK there is currently no way to run it outside of eclipse. Though since it is open sourced it may be possible to get it working as a standalone, I don't think anyone has. Check out http://www.droiddraw.org/ for an alternative editor. Between that and just editing the xml files you should be able to do without eclipse.

Comment: Setting something like that up sounds complicated...

Answer (score 1):

There is no independent way to create a user interface outside of an IDE. Most online programs use mockups, which help you build and design your user interface. Balsamiq in particular lets you then export the mockups in xml format.

You can then apply them to the xml layout files in Eclipse.

Hope this helps.

[Link to Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/)